# Draggable and customize DIV's

Tags: jquery, customization, draggable

In my web page, rumonet.pt/index2.php  I have the 3 'tabs', they are DIV's, and they can be moved with jquery. If u want to try it, just select the title, and move them arround...

What i needed to do, is to when you move it to top of another, the other DIV gets to the side, allowing people to order them at their will...

i know i have to use

```
   $('#noticias #titulo').bind('mousemove mousedown', function(){

);
```

and the offset() vars...

But i've been trying around for a long time to make this to work, but nothing...

can anyone give me a hint, or some lights about the problem? :ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at `dragable()` and `sortable()` ? Might just do the trick you're after

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QWgRF/